# Как открыть свернутое приложение одним нажатием?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема заключается в том, что при нажатии правой кнопкой мыши по свернутому значку приложения, событие `Click` не может распознать правую клавишу и открывает приложение вместо меню.

`notifyIcon1` хорошо работает через событие `DoubleClick`, но хочется, чтобы свернутое приложение открывалось по одному клику, и ничего не мешало открытию меню.

```
private void notifyIcon1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
}
```

Предлагают так же использовать различие левого и правого нажатия, но появляется ошибка в таком коде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У `EventArgs` нет свойства `Button`, передавайте в параметр объект типа `MouseEventArgs`:

```
private void notifyIcon1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
   {
      // обрабатываем щелчок левой
   }
   else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
   {
      // обрабатываем щелчок правой
   }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает без `else if`